# Gradle 2.6 doesn't resolve dependency from bintray

Tags: gradle, bintray

I'm building pretty straigh-forward:

```
$ gradle clean test war -b build.gradle
```

Gradle says:

```
:clean UP-TO-DATE
:compileJava

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':compile'.
> Could not find mvc-tools.jar (net.virtalab:mvc-tools:2.1).
Searched in the following locations:
     http://dl.bintray.com/virtalab/maven/net/virtalab/mvc-tools/2.1/mvc-tools-2.1.jar
```

While there is JAR on given URL:

```
$ wget http://dl.bintray.com/virtalab/maven/net/virtalab/mvc-tools/2.1/mvc-tools-2.1.jar
...
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 27222 (27K) [application/java-archive]
...
$ file mvc-tools-2.1.jar
mvc-tools-2.1.jar: Zip archive data, at least v1.0 to extract
```

My build.gradle is:

```
repositories {
//local maven repo if possible
mavenLocal()
//bintray
maven {
    url "http://dl.bintray.com/virtalab/maven"
}
//our jcenter cache
maven {
    url 'http://maven.virtadev.net/jcenter'
}
}
```

What I already did?

- Launch with --debug (still no idea why gradle stucks)
- rm -rf .gradle

Comment: Are you getting this error also `Could not find org.sonatype.oss:oss-parent:7.`?

Comment: Wow, that's really puzzling. Can you run gradle in debug? Maybe we'll see some clues there.

Comment: @JBaruch here it is. I did a debug run: https://gist.github.com/kyberorg/b0c13e82e0b07cc2a0d5

Comment: @KarthikeyanVaithilingam no I don't.

Comment: Can you please check whether the artifact (mvc-tools jar) is already cached in either your Maven local cache (.m2) or in Gradle local cache (.gradle)?

Comment: @JBaruch I found mvc-tools at .gradle cache, but there was only .pom file bot .jar one. I found it at: ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/
I've deleted ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/net.virtalab/mvc-tools and
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.15/descriptors/net.virtalab/mvc-tools 
and re-run build. Build failed with exactly same error and as previously there is only .pom file

Comment: What about `/usr/local/jenkins/.m2/repository/net/virtalab/mvc-tools/2.1/mvc-tools-2.1.jar`? Does it exist?

Comment: @JBaruch there no `/usr/local/jenkins/.m2/` at all. Additionally there is no `/usr/local/jenkins/workspace/job-name-here/.m2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally problem solved by deleting `~/.gradle` directory

Comment: misunderstanding occured somewhere. I tried deleting: `/usr/local/jenkins/workspace/job-name-here/.gradle`